# Using netty's SslHandler::close(ChannelHandlerContext, ChannelPromise)

Tags: netty

I have a netty TLS client and server that are able to talk to each other and I want at some point the TLS session to be closed but without closing the unrelying tcp connection (and respective netty channels).

The JavaDoc for SslHandler seems to imply that this is possible, and there's a method in there that seems to do exactly that:

```
public void close(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final ChannelPromise promise) { ... }
```

However, when I invoke this in my server handler like this:

```
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {

    // ...

    ChannelPromise endTls = ctx.newPromise().addListener(f -> {
        log.debug("This is never reached :-(");
    });

    sslHandler.close(ctx, endTls);

    // ...
}
```

... nothing happens, i.e.

1. endTls never completes;
2. On the client side no listeners of clientSslHandler.sslCloseFuture() are ever notified.

I've tried using close(ctx, promise) from the server, from the client, and from both but the effect is always the same - the future doesn't complete, and the peer receives no close_notify message.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this ? The method you are using definitely is not for this use-case.

Comment: It's about defeating firewalls. Imagine you have a program on site A and another on site B, but only site B has a public endpoint and can accept incoming tcp connections. The idea is to have a tls server and a tls client on each site, and do TLS connections in any direction (any peer can act as a tls client and/or tls server). Note that this can be done without nesting tls connections. Also note that all the tcp connections are always from site A to site B... All you have to do is be able to have multiple tls sessions on the same tcp connection...

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is `sslHandler.close()` or `sslHandler.close(promise)`. Let me know if it does what you want to do.

Comment: I got everything to work with sslHandler.close(promise). However, this API is deprecated in the version of Netty I'm using: 4.1.24. Any idea why the sslHandler.close(ctx, endTls) version didn't work?

Comment: Yep I know its deprecated but this may be our fault and we may should "undeprecate" it.  Thats why I am asking.

Comment: I tried using closeOutbound but I don't understand how we can leverage open connection if SslHandler on the other side [closes connection](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/849649b48d3c8fbf86565b8fa28a07f8b673adaf/handler/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/ssl/SslHandler.java#L1091-L1101) anyway.  Did I understand the purpose (keep using same connection after closing ssl session) of closeOutbound correctly?